# Spotify play endpoint won't recognize uri

Tags: javascript, api, axios, spotify

I've built a Spotify player in JS and I have a function that sends playback commands. So far, it successfully modifies playback for everything **except playing a specific track**.

When I try to pass in a one item array of track URI's to play a particular song, it simply resumes playing the current track and not the specified URI.

I'm able to get this endpoint to work on their test site as well as in Postman with the same syntax, but it's not working in my code. Any insight would be appreciated.

```js
function playerAction(token, action, desiredValue) {
  var method;
  var params = {};
  switch (action) {
    case "next":
      method = "post";
      break;
    case "previous":
      method = "post";
      break;
    case "shuffle":
      method = "put";
      params = { state: desiredValue };
      break;
    case "volume":
      method = "put";
      params = { volume_percent: desiredValue };
      break;
    case "play":
      method = "put";
      if (desiredValue) params = { uris: [desiredValue] };
      break;
    default:
      method = "put";
  }
  return axios({
    method: method,
    url: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/${action}`,
    params: params,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  });
}
```

I also added a console.log into the play case just to make sure the data was making it there. Output seems to confirm that's working:

```
you asked spotify.js to play with desiredValue: spotify:track:2GIfOOa8hAywfzZptFz3xK
```

Answer (score 0):

After staring at axios's response via console.log, I noticed that in the config, a key called 'data' had a value of undefined. So naturally, I added a key called data to the axios call and moved the object with uri key to there. And voila, it worked.

```js
function playerAction(token, action, desiredValue) {
  var method;
  var params = {};
  var data = {};
  switch (action) {
    case "next":
      method = "post";
      break;
    case "previous":
      method = "post";
      break;
    case "shuffle":
      method = "put";
      params = { state: desiredValue };
      break;
    case "volume":
      method = "put";
      params = { volume_percent: desiredValue };
      break;
    case "play":
      method = "put";
      if (desiredValue) data = { uris: [desiredValue] };
      break;
    default:
      method = "put";
  }
  return axios({
    method: method,
    url: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/${action}`,
    params: params,
    data: data,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  });
}
```